# Operator new with address hint (create an object near another object)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, new-operator

I want to create a lot of objects of the same type, and i want them to be relatively close in memory to avoid page misses.

Is there a way to tell the operating system (windows platform) to allocate memory as close as possible to a given address? (address hint)
Some function hidden deep in MSDN?

I know there's operator placement new, but i'm trying to find out if there's any other trick.
And yes i know how to create custom memory management with placement new....

Pseudocode (if exists):

```
Myclass *a = new Myclass();

Myclass *b = AloocateNear(a,sizeof(Myclass));
```

Comment: I'd just use placement new.

Comment: Yea, but i don't want to allocate a predefined size, and then handle deallocations and memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::vector`. The items at index X and X+1 are *guaranteed* to be next to each other.

---

As noted in comments (thanks sheu), this solution makes it hard to destruct individual objects.

Comment: It would be more efficient to just allocate X times sizeof(Myclass) and use placement new to create the objects there. Although yea, it's a nice trick with similar effect.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: "just allocate X times sizeof(Myclass) and use placement new to create the objects there" is basically what `std::vector` is.

Comment: Using `std::vector` is not "a nice trick". Re-inventing it for no reason whatsoever is a "trick". Why do you think your way is "more efficient"?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't destroy individual objects in this case using `std::vector`, without destroying the entire vector.

Comment: True, it'd make a poor reusable pool. If that's a requirement here (and it wasn't stated), then the answer to the question is "no".

Comment: @sheu It can still be done, by using placement new of the individual entries in the vector. And to everyone else, yes this is a "hack" and a poor mans memory pool.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: does this still cause the object destructors to be (erroneously) called again on vector destruction?

Comment: The main difference here than what i've asked for is that i'd have to manage object disposal and memory fragmentation myself. Disposing of an object in the middle of the vector isn't trivial.

Comment: @sheu Yes, so extra care has to be taken in the destructors to check for such things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: this doesn't strike me as a good solution then, since it requires *intensive* changes to the pooled objects (as opposed to purely *extensive* changes to the container).

Comment: @sheu I didn't say it was a _good_ solution, it's just a _possible_ solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think this is a big enough caveat that it would rate a mention in your answer post.

Answer (score 2):

Placement new is the answer.  If you're *really* concerned about locality, then you're obviously going to have to be using placement new with a memory pool of some kind.

Comment: I know that, the question is if there's another function hidden somewhere in MSDN that might do something like that

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: I don't believe so.  I don't think the compile writers would implement an extension for such if there already exists a perfectly adequate (read: placement new) solution for the problem in the language itself.  But then again, they *are* Microsoft, so who knows...